# R Studio Shiny support email, SMS push on mobile

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny-server

Does R Studio Shiny can be scheduled or configured on demand push distribution of reports (eg. email, SMS, etc.) on web portal or devices such as mobile?

Comment: There is no such thing as "R studio Shiny", R Studio is an IDE for R, Shiny is an R library for making online reports, and Shiny server is a server application for running shiny reports on web server... And, what shiny does is it makes and displays the online reports, it does not send SMS...

Comment: pushoverR sends push notifications. You could have R create rmarkdown documents & convert to HTML & save, then have pushoverR send a push notification or email with a link to that report.